# Are the moderators able to rename tags for this site?

Tags: support, tags, moderators

Sometimes users create tags with typos. Replacing the tag with the right spelling/format, e.g., b17 → b-17, doesn't work due to the similarity.

I asked about it before in chat, one of the suggestions I received [was](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50332537#50332537):

> Other option might be to remove b17, let it die [in 24 hours], and then add b-17

Now, it's happened again with the antonov-an2 (should have been antonov-an-2). It's minor, but imagine a 7478 and not the proper [747-8](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boeing-747-8) (link to tag).

I applied the suggestion for the antonov, and left a clear revision notice.

> retag "antonov-an-2" (with the 2nd dash) in 24h once the tag with the typo (missing 2nd dash) is removed from the database

But the tag with the typo was reapplied, and applied to yet another post.

Having no means of communicating directly with the editors (not all visit the chat), this time I left a comment, on both posts to wait 24 hours and apply the right tag.

> **Note to editors:** The applicable aircraft tag is missing the 2nd dash, please don't tag for 24 hours, until the one with the typo is automatically deleted, then retag with [antonov-an-2].

Guess what, even that [did not work](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/65718/revisions).

All this is too much and inefficient. So, apart from synonym requests (which leaves a trace and is not the right request), can the moderators here apply spelling corrections?

---

Hoping it is a yes, here are some:

- [b17-flying-fortress](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/b17-flying-fortress) → [boeing-b-17-flying-fortress](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boeing-b-17-flying-fortress)
- [antonov-225](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antonov-225) → [antonov-an-225-mriya](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antonov-an-225-mriya) (it's like if we had airbus-320 not airbus-a320)
- [antonov-an2](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antonov-an2) → [antonov-an-2](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antonov-an-2)

Comment: Im missing something: Why is `antonov-an2` better as `antonov-an-2`? Does the extra dash add something i'm missing?

Comment: @Jamiec: Just like b17/b-17. Wikipedia has high standards for article names, so I resort to those. I've given examples of more commonly used tags, and how they would look if they were misspelled. If the answer is no, or it's too much trouble, let me know.

Comment: Do you have a canonical list of all the tags you think should be renamed? Youve given 3 examples. Is this it? Are there more?  If you want to edit the exhaustive list into your question it'll get us one step closer to [status-completed] I suppose.

Comment: I've responded in chat for [the curious](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50795770#50795770).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, moderators can rename tags. It is handled internally as a migration (from old tag to new tag), but in essence it looks exactly like a rename from an end-user point-of-view.

If we can come to an agreement/consensus as to  what the renames should be I'm happy to do it.