# What should the tag format be for aircraft models?

Tags: discussion, tags

We favor creating tags for aircraft models ([Do we need a tag for each airplane model we mention?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3423/14897)).

I typically create tags that include the manufacturer's name (consistent with [boeing-747](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boeing-747), [airbus-a380](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-a380), etc.). Such recent tag creation ([tupolev-tu-204](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tupolev-tu-204)) was deleted in favor of just the model name, for consistency with that manufacturer's existing tags, which I have missed due to the search engine wanting 3+ characters (I only typed "tu"). Existing examples include [tu-104](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tu-104) and [tu-114](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tu-114).

- [Revision history of that post](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/69774/revisions)
- [Chat transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51726827#51726827)

---

Note: Old tags can be renamed ([Are the moderators able to rename tags for this site?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3833/14897)).

**Q:** What should our policy be *moving forward* regarding new tags for aircraft models?

Do we:

1. Keep the format that is consistent with what was used, even if that omits the manufacturer?
2. Use the manufacturer format regardless of what was used, and request renames for old tags (which should be easy since the moderators would target **one manufacturer per request**)?
3. [Something else.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally, I would prefer to keep the manufacturer in the tag name.

While I don't think anyone will have trouble recognizing something like [b737](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/b737) or [a320](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a320) (even though the 'b' is just colloquial and not actually part of the aircraft name,) I can imagine more confusion occurring with less-well-known models. For example, I could see something like [314](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/314) or [b314](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/b314) not necessarily being as obvious to many people as [boeing-314](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boeing-314), especially for readers who aren't as familiar with aviation history.

Also, I could see using the non-standard 'b' prefix for Boeing aircraft perhaps causing confusion with the standard "B-" prefix used to designate bombers.

Comment: On reflection, I change my mind to your POV.

Comment: So, in your opinion, should we also use the full manufacturer's name when it is fairly long or not as recognizable to the general public as the prefix? I'm thinking about Mikoyan Gurevich corporation in particular, but I'm sure there are others that are more known for their prefix than their actual name.

Comment: @AEhere Yeah, MiG is kind of an extreme case. Like I commented on kevin's answer, though, I'd lean toward just using the normal designation for military aircraft anyway, since they seem to be better known by those. I would agree that [tag:mig-35] is probably better than [tag:mikoyan-gurevich-mig-35], just as I think [tag:f-35] is probably more appropriate than [tag:lockheed-martin-f-35]. That said, if you have more thoughts on the best way to determine when one format or the other should be used, feel free to add another answer.

Answer (score 7):

For civilian aircraft, the name of the manufacturer should prefix the model, separated by a hyphen. [boeing-747](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boeing-747), [airbus-a320](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airbus-a320).

For military aircraft, it should be [f-16](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/f-16), [a-10](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-10) etc.

The short form [b747](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/b747) is only for people who are familiar with airplane models. I don't see any benefit of it, except maybe saving a few keystrokes. We should aim the site at a broader audience.

[b-747](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/b-747) makes no sense. It is either [boeing-747](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boeing-747) or [b747](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/b747), and I prefer the long format.

Comment: Why would it be [c-5] and not [lockheed-c-5]?

Comment: For what it's worth, I agree. With military aircraft, I think they tend to be much better known by their military designations. The average person asking a question about a military aircraft often probably won't even know the manufacturer (with the notable exception of passenger airliners in military transport roles, where more people will think "Boeing 747" than "VC-25," for example.)

Comment: @reirab: Let's say I'm new and I want to ask about the su25 (intentionally missing the dash to make a point), and I typed that in the tag box, it *will* autocomplete to "sukhoi-su-25". IMO it's our job to make sure the site is in good shape, autocomplete will do the rest for the new users.

Comment: @ymb1 tag synonyms should take care of that. (e.g. "b747" --> "Boeing-747")

Comment: @kevin: Synonyms is more work, I'm asking for new tags before they're used more than once, i.e., once created, what format should we make sure that tag follows.

Comment: One nice thing about this convention is that it makes it obvious that, say, the [tag:cirrus-sr22] is a civilian aircraft while the [tag:sr-71] is a military aircraft. Likewise for [tag:c-130] and [tag:cessna-c150].